# bit comparison in loop on AVRs

Tags: c, bit, avr, led, operations

I'm learning about bit logic in C on AVRs and I have a problem.

I want to compare an "i" bit (from the right) from int8_t variable and if it is 1, then do the next instruction, but it doesn't work. Here's what I write:

```
if (variable & (1<<i)==(1<<i)) instruction;
```

In example for following data:

```
uint8_t dot=0101;
PORTC=1;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    PORTB = fourDigit[i];
    if (dot & (1<<i)==(1<<i)) PORTB--;
    PORTC<<=1;
}
```

The dot (as it is connected to PB0) should illuminate on the first and third digit, but at present it lamps on every digit. What's the problem?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by *bit masking*. If you want to check whether or not an `i`'th bit of `a` is 1 you will do something like this:

```
if (a & (1 << i))
{
    // Do something
}
```

This way all of the bits of `a` except the `i`'th one will be *AND*ed with zeros, thus getting a value of zero. The `i`'th bit will be *AND*ed with `1`, thus not changing it's value. So the `if` condition will be true in case the bit is not zero, and false otherwise. 
 The comparison code you are presenting should work as well, but I suspect the `dot` variable is not containing the value you think it is containing. `uint8_t dot=0101;` makes it to be equal to `101` in **octal** base (due to the leading zero) or `65` in decimal. Not `101` in binary.

Comment: I've copied your code and it works. My should work as well, but it didn't. As to the number inside uin8_t dot, I've used it in binary (0b0101).
Thank you

Comment: Yep. The precedence is the case here. You should enclose the left part of the `==` operator in brackets.